# Python - How to hide output after killed specified process

Tags: android, python

now i try to create a python script to get Android logcats automatically

below seciton is part of my codes

```
logcat_process = subprocess.Popen('adb logcat -v time > logcat.log', shell=True)

time.sleep(5)

os.kill((logcat_process.pid)+1, signal.SIGKILL)
```

however, every time after os.kill terminate the process,
it will print message like

```
"/bin/sh: line 1: 13961 Killed: 9               adb logcat -v time > logcat.log"**
```

on the screen.

Does anybody have any idea how to hide this message?

I want the result print of script more simple and clear....

Comment: Did you try something similar to clear, if you want to clear the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
logcat_process = subprocess.Popen('adb logcat -v time > logcat.log', shell=True)
time.sleep(5)   

save_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(r'/youlib..../trash.txt', 'w')

os.kill((logcat_process.pid)+1, signal.SIGKILL)

# regain stdout to screen
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

It will divert the stdout to the `trash.txt` file at the `kill` operation.

Answer (score 0):

redirect the stdout/stderr in python and add a filter.