# how to suppress "Killed" output when calling os.killpg() in python script?

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script which invokes multiple processes and those processes can invoke more processes.
To kill all of them I've used following script:

```
os.setpgrp()
# Code which invokes multiple processes
# 
# Almost all work got completed but some processes are still running which I don't need any more.
os.killpg(0, signal.SIGKILL)
```

When running the above python script, I get output with print `Killed` in the end.

If I change the signal `signal.SIGKILL` to `signal.SIGTERM`, then output changes from `Killed` to `Terminated`. I want to suppress this info so that it doesn't confuse user because it is not relevant to him. Is there any way to suppress this from the stdout?

EDIT 1: As pointed out by @SiHa, there is a related question: [Python - How to hide output after killed specified process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265334/python-how-to-hide-output-after-killed-specified-process)

But my question is little bit different from that in the sense that `os.killpgrp()` is killing my own python script, and therefore answer to that question is not helping me in diverting the output.
When, I tried the proposed answer from the above mentioned related question, I found that `trash.txt` gets created but still `Killed` is being printed in the std output. The file `trash.txt` remains empty. 
A possible reason seems to me that my python script is getting killed so no further code is getting executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to hide output after killed specified process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265334/python-how-to-hide-output-after-killed-specified-process)

Comment: @SiHa: I've edited my question to explain how that answer to that question is not helping me. Thanks for suggesting me the related question though.

Comment: Only the shutdown process of the operating system is intended to use SIGKILL. Use SIGTERM and catch the signal.

Comment: @ceving thanks I'll take care of it. But is there any issue if I use SIGKILL instead. I've seen couple of posts in SO where SIGKILL was used.

Comment: @VivekAgrawal you can not catch SIGKILL and this means the program has not chance to terminate correctly. And this is the reason why it is worth to be notified in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question, following statement was killing my own python script:

```
os.killpg(0, signal.SIGKILL)
```

To solve my problem I had to create a process group of all the children and killing them using:

```
os.killpg(<pgid_of_children>, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Thanks @ceving for explaining the benefit of SIGTERM over SIGKILL.